# SDL text not showing up c++

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to write text to an SDL_Window but I can't get the text to show up. And i've tried messing around with different colors and all of that stuff.

Here's my code

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == (-1))
    {
        printf("Could not initialize SDL: %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }

    int WINWIDTH = 640;
    int WINHEIGHT = 480;

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Text Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Fonts\\arial.ttf", 24);

    SDL_Color White = { 255, 0, 0 }; 

    SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "put your text here", White);

    SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);

    SDL_Rect Message_rect;
    Message_rect.x = 0;  
    Message_rect.y = 0; 
    Message_rect.w = 100; 
    Message_rect.h = 100; 

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, NULL, &Message_rect);

    system("pause");

    exit(0);

}
```

I have tried multiple ways of creating text but none of it works.

Comment: What this `"Fonts\\arial.ttf"` is supposed to mean?

Comment: That's where the arial font is in the projects files.

Comment: '\\' is Windows only path delimiter, are you on Windows?

Check if `Sans` is not NULL after this: `TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Fonts\\arial.ttf", 24);` 

You should pass absolute path to TTF_OpenFont otherwise it will try to open file from current folder that could be far from what you expect.

Comment: Before I forgot the s on Fonts and it was giving me an error plus I have tried the absolute path before.

Comment: Checking the return value on all these calls that return pointers would be a very good start.

Comment: Hmm I just copied and pasted someone elses code that works for this and the same thing happens!

Comment: Using TTF_Init () would also be useful.

Comment: TTF_Init() didn't fix it.

Comment: I didn't say it would fix it, I said it wouldn't work without it. Now, assuming your path to the font is correct, you will at least have a font to take to the next stage.

Comment: Oh but yeah I made sure the font path is right

Comment: So can anyone help??